# Change link color or link CSS in Google Maps API

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, styles

I'm using Google Maps as an API to display a map on a client page. In the info window when the user clicks a marker I want the user to select that particular location and proceed to next page. Works fine with a link, however, visually this link gains to little visual weight. I want it to stand out more.

Is it possible, and if so how, to modify the styling of the links in the info window in the Google Maps API?

Comment: Place the infowindow content in a DIV with a specific class and control the look of your links with CSS.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Show us your approach. We won't do your job. This is not, how StackOverflow works!

Comment: Yeah sorry, that wasn't my intention. I'm a designer and I'm doing some research to see if it's at all possible since the approach to the design is dependant to if it's possible. I got stuck in that I tried to Google it, read the Google Maps API and read forums an found nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your infowindow content like  this:

```
infoWindow.setContent("<div><a class='link' href='#'>...</a></div>")
```

So you can easily use the CSS selector to style the link.

Comment: Hey, if my answer was helpfull and worked for you, please vote it as the correct answer! thx and you are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Im new here but Im guessing it's the massive checkbox on the page. If so, done. :)